# Passing Multi-Select Picklist values to child record with URL hack

Tags: urlhacking, multi-select

I've tried every hack I can think of to pull the selected values of a multi-select picklist into a child record with a URL hack.  The field name is the same on each object.

**Account.Required_Operating_Data__c**

**Filing.Required_Operating_Data__c**

Is it just not an option?  So far I've tried:

This one was trying to put the selected values in the Required_Operating_Data__c field on Account, into the field on the Edit screen.  Inspecting the element shows the 'chosen' side to have an _selected tag.

```
/a1U/e?00Ne0000001EFHO_selected={!Account.Required_Operating_Data__c}
```

This was just trying to put the list into the actual field.

```
/a1U/e?00Ne0000001EFHO={!Account.Required_Operating_Data__c}
```

This one was using field names.  (Now I'm just guessing)

```
/a1U/e?required_operating_data__c={!Account.Required_Operating_Data__c}
```

So, for example:

- A user creates an Account record.
- The account record multipick has the following options A, B, C, D, E,
  F
- The user selects 'C' and 'F'.
- When they click the [New Filing] button, it should pre-fill the field on Filing with 'C' and 'F'.
- The next time an account is created the user may select any combination of other options, and then create a Filing using THOSE selected values.
- Rinse/Repeat

The use case is that while the user may have selected None, Some, or All of the options on Account, they may need to adjust the list on the Filing, but the default state should be based on the Account.

Comment: is VF an option?

Comment: Only as a last resort, but it is an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the original field id:

/a1U/e?00Ne0000001EFHO=picklistvalue

If you want to pass multiple values, just repeat the parameter:

/a1U/e?00Ne0000001EFHO=picklistvalue1&00Ne0000001EFHO=picklistvalue2

Comment: That works to auto-populate based on the picklist choices, but if I want the selected values on the parent record to be also selected on the child, it has to evaluate the field, correct?  Your suggestion would hard-code values I believe?

Comment: Yes, you need to evaluate the parent record field value and append it to the url with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am looking to auto populate multi select picklist values from Parent to child opportunity.. Did anyone succeed in doing that..Can you please share the code snippet. Thank you

Comment: I've heard nothing of news, but I'm working on using a Visual Workflow to resolve the issue.  Details to follow.