# PageReference getParameters().put non-unique parameters to pass multipicklist values

Tags: apex, pagereference, multi-select

I'm trying to pass parameters via URL to a multi-picklist field, but I'm finding that it seems to be impossible to build a pageRefence with non-unique parameters.

```
pageRef.getParameters().put(00Ne0000001cwJ4, 'value1');
pageRef.getParameters().put(00Ne0000001cwJ4, 'value2');
```

becomes this in the URL: &00Ne0000001cwJ4=value2

Even doing something like:

```
new pageRefence(url);
```

where you've built the full URL that includes the parameters yourself will still end up stripping the additional values. Are there any workarounds to this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a semicolon delimited list (e.g. `param=value1;value2`)?

Comment: I actually did, but passing it with a semicolon as a delimiter unfortunately does not work. From what I've seen, I believe that it tries to treat the whole string as 1 value (which doesn't work since it won't be a proper value).

Answer (score 1):

As Adrian suggests, on the requesting side:

```
String[] values = ...;
Map<String, String> params = pageRef.getParameters();
params.put('00Ne0000001cwJ4', String.join(values, ';'));
```

and on the receiving side:

```
Map<String, String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
String[] values = params.get('00Ne0000001cwJ4').split(';');
```

The parameter values are automatically URL encoded and the appropriate `?` or `&` parameter delimiter added as needed.

For the general, case choose a character (or characters) in the `join`/`split` that you know will not be present in any of the parameter values.

Comment: I'm just trying to pass values to a standard Salesforce page to populate some fields. With your solution I'd have to have an entirely custom page with a controller on the receiving side, which means anytime we want to add new fields to the layout, there would to be a code edit. Not very user friendly for regular admins & not a sustainable solution in the long-run.

Comment: @Julien Ok I see. Do standard Salesforce pages support a syntax for this e.g. doe the semi-colon separation work? I've never seen a "URL hack" for this though there is this unaccepted answer post [Passing Multi-Select Picklist values to child record with URL hack](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69089/passing-multi-select-picklist-values-to-child-record-with-url-hack).

Comment: unfortunately semi-colon separation does not work. The link you posted is indeed the only way I've found to go about it (ie: having your URL being &00Ne0000001cwJ4=value1&00Ne0000001cwJ4=value2), but if trying to do it via PageRefence, it removes all the duplicate parameters :/